# Teradata make FOLLOWING dynamic based on a column

Tags: teradata

I have a table with columns item, store, date, and fcst. For each item store day I need to sum the next x number of days of forecast, however x changes for each item store combination. This following code does not work and I was advised that X FOLLOWING has to be replaced with a static innteger FOLLOWING:

Doesn’t run:

```
SELECT
ITEMNBR,
STORENBR,
DT,
SUM(FCST)OVER(PARTITION BY STORENBR,ITEMNBR ORDER BY DT BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND X ROWS FOLLOWING) AS VALUE

FROM TABLENAME
```

Does run:

```
SELECT
ITEMNBR,
STORENBR,
DT,
SUM(FCST)OVER(PARTITION BY STORENBR,ITEMNBR ORDER BY DT BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 7 ROWS FOLLOWING) AS VALUE

FROM TABLENAME
```

Any fix or suggested workaround?

Comment: From where are you planning to get the value of X?

Comment: And is there a known list of possible values for `x`?

Comment: Generate SQL expression dynamically (substituting X with the desired static value) and submit for execution via "execute immediate".